# MySQL - Clear buffer/cache

Tags: mysql, caching, commit

I have a Java application (ETL) inserting bulk data in a table (a few million records). Then I have a Python application that is calling the Java application, waiting for it to finish and then the Python code is querying a view that is using this table. In the Java application, I explicitly call COMMIT.

When I select the data from the Python app, the data is not returned, as if it hasn't been completely committed. If I run the same query just a few seconds later, the data is there. It looks like a buffer/cache issue to me or maybe the transaction is not really completed.

It definitely has something to do with the volume of data, as there is no issue when I try to load less data in a different table and perform the query a second after.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Millions of records within a transaction? Ya I think the transaction wasnt finished jet

Comment: So how can I make sure to wait for the transaction to be finished?

Comment: You can check proceslist or check show innodb status (or show engine innodb status for newer versions of mysql) that should help

Comment: I did check the process list manually and I don't see anything running other than the select statement